# WPF PasswordBox automatically clears when move focus

Tags: c#, wpf

I am building a new user form where there is a need for users to create a Password box.

I am using a `PasswordBox` for this. However as soon as the user moves to the next box in the form (or selects create button) the password box clears.

So the password property in the code behind is always an empty string.

Is there any reason why this is occurring? I want to be able to use the data entered to create my users.

I have including the XAML below:

```
 <PasswordBox x:Name="Password1_passwordBox" Password="Password1" PasswordChar="X" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="25" Margin="138,201,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="85"/>
```

Any help appreciated

Comment: Could you please give more detail? A bit more source code may be.

Comment: Do you have any code behind changing values in background or something? We need more data here.

Comment: Hi Guys, in the codebox I am just try to access the passwordbox.password but because the box keeps clearing it is always an empty string.

Comment: Is there any Style applied globally, try `Style="{x:Null}"` and check if it works

Comment: Hi there is no style applied globally and the automatic clearing is not occurring on the Text boxes on the same form.

Comment: quick update. when I changed the object I was placing the Password Box in from a user control to a view the issue disappeared. Has anybody else had this issue when using UserControls?

Answer (score 1):

As it stands in the code given, the `PasswordBox` should work as you expect. There is something else clearing it out. You should check the other logic in code-behind and any control templates, styles, etc that would be tied to the `PasswordBox`.

Additionally, you should check for any errors that come up during execution.

Answer (score 0):

You may have changed Password1_passwordBox.password property or something like that in your code behind.